# Running SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org doesn't create a scratch org

Tags: lightning-web-components, scratch-org, vs-code

When I run the command SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org.. it doesn't creating the scratch org, the banner of the command is still there and the command prompt doesn't show any error. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Command Prompt]

Comment: According to Salesforce, you need to do the following first: Set up your Salesforce DX project, Authorize the Dev Hub org and Create the scratch org definition file. Can you check? You can also try to do it with the command line, it should give you more insight if it fails. more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm

Comment: Thank You, Kevan, for the reply! I have found the solution here :https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iq1MQAQ